# How to pass a parameter in a fluent API before calling any function?

Tags: java

I have this kind of class

```
public class AImpl implements A {
    private String variable = "init";

    @Override
    public A choice(A... choices) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public A execute() {
        variable = "execute";
        return this;
    }
}
```

I can use it like this (simple example)

```
new AImpl().choice(
    new AImpl[] {
        new AImpl().execute(),
        new AImpl()    
    };
)
```

or like this (more complex example, with variable expected value)

```
new AImpl().choice(                       //variable == "init"
    new AImpl[] {
        new AImpl().execute(),              //variable == "init". Set to "execute"
        new AImpl().choice(                 //variable == "init"
            new AImpl[] {
                new AImpl()                 //variable == "init"
            }
        ), 
        new AImpl().execute().choice(       //variable == "init". Set to "execute"
            new AImpl[] {
                new AImpl(),                //variable == "execute"
                new AImpl()                 //variable == "execute"
            }
        ),    
    };
)
```

**What I'm trying to achieve**

Each time there is a choice, I would like to propagate the last value of `variable` to each new instances. Here is graph version of the complex example where I encircled what I called *propagation*

[image]

**What is my question**

How can I propagate this `variable` to all the objects in the `choices` list **before** calling any other function (before calling `execute` in the simple example above, because this function uses (and can modify) this variable).

**What I have tried**

- I can not do it using the constructor since I don't have a reference to the variable

  ```
  public AImpl(String variable) {
      this.variable = variable;
  }
  ```
- This code will not work because the variable will be set after all functions

  ```
  @Override
  public A choice(A... choices) {
      for(A a : choices) {
          a.setVariable(variable);
      }
  }
  ```
- I tried with a `Builder` (eg set all the values and only create the instance at the end, from the choice function for example). But it make sense to chained the functions `execute` or `choice` (`...execute().execute().choice()...`). So the builder become difficult to create and can become really big.
- I also tried to move the variable to a `context` class, but it is not working if in the `choices` I have another choice (case of the more complex example). Here is my current context class

  ```
  public class Context {
      private static Context instance = null;
      private String variable;

      private Context(){};

      public String getVariable() {
          return variable;
      }

      public void setVariable(String variable) {
          this.variable = variable;
      }

      public static void set(String variable) {
          if(Context.instance == null)
              Context.instance = new Context();
          Context.instance.setVariable(variable);
      }

      public static String get() {
          if(Context.instance == null)
              throw new NullPointerException();
          return Context.instance.getVariable();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Your question is not very clear...

Comment: I think you need some kind of builder object that constructs representations of all the data you need, and only at the end your builder constructs the real objects.

Comment: Ok I will try to reformulate

Comment: I update my question about the `Builder`. I will reformulate the other part soon

Comment: When you say `new AImpl[ new AImpl() ]` do you mean `new AImpl[] { new AImpl() }` ?

Comment: Definitely. Shame on me for this typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working solution based on the `Context` approach (see *What I have tried ?*)

**The main idea**

There are two mains ideas. The first one is to replace (inside the context object) the single variable by a `Stack` of variables like this one

```
Stack<String> variables = new Stack<>();
```

I push the first variable in the first constructor and them I can access and modify it using `pop/push` function

```
String variable = Context.pop();
//Do something with variable
Context.push("anotherValue");
```

The second main idea is to duplicate the value on the top of the stack each time I create a new choice **and** to remove it at the end of each choice.

**My code**

Here is my code, if it can help someone else. I'm sure there is a lot of things to do to improve it, but it solved my original problem.

- TestSo.java

  ```
  public class TestSo {
      @Test
      public void testSo() {
          AImpl.create().choice(
                  new ChoiceList()
                          .add(AChoice.create().execute())
                          .add(AChoice.create().choice(
                                  new ChoiceList().add(AChoice.create())
                          ))
                          .add(AChoice.create().execute().choice(
                                  new ChoiceList()
                                          .add(AChoice.create())
                                          .add(AChoice.create())
                          ))
          );
      }
  }
  ```
- A.java

  ```
  public interface A {
      A choice(ChoiceList choices);
      A execute();
  }
  ```
- AAbstract.java

  ```
  public class AAbstract implements A {
      @Override
      public A choice(ChoiceList choices) {
          return this;
      }

      @Override
      public A execute() {
          String variable = Context.get();

          //...

          Context.set("execute");
          return this;
      }
  }
  ```
- AImpl.java

  ```
  public class AImpl extends AAbstract {
      private AImpl() {
          Context.set("init");
      }

      public static AImpl create() {
          return new AImpl();
      }
  }
  ```
- AChoice.java

  ```
  public class AChoice extends AAbstract {
      private AChoice() {
          Context.duplicate();
      }

      public static AChoice create() {
          return new AChoice();
      }

      @Override
      public AChoice choice(ChoiceList choices) {
          super.choice(choices);
          return this;
      }

      @Override
      public AChoice execute() {
          super.execute();
          return this;
      }
  }
  ```
- ChoiceList.java

  ```
  public class ChoiceList {
      private List<AChoice> choices = new ArrayList<>();

      public ChoiceList add(AChoice choice) {
          Context.remove();
          choices.add(choice);
          return this;
      }
  }
  ```
- Context.java

  ```
  public class Context {
      private static Context instance = null;
      private Stack<String> variables = new Stack<>();

      private Context(){};
      public String peek() {return variables.peek();}
      public String pop() {return variables.pop();}
      public void fork() {variables.push(variables.peek());}
      public void push(String variable) {variables.push(variable);}

      public static void set(String variable) {
          if(Context.instance == null)
              Context.instance = new Context();
          Context.instance.push(variable);
      }

      public static String get() {
          if(Context.instance == null)
              throw new NullPointerException();
          return Context.instance.pop();
      }

     public static void remove() {
          if(Context.instance == null)
              throw new NullPointerException();
          Context.instance.pop();
      }

      public static void duplicate() {
          if(Context.instance == null)
              throw new NullPointerException();
          Context.instance.fork();
      }

      public static String read() {
          if(Context.instance == null)
              throw new NullPointerException();
          return Context.instance.peek();
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that new AImpl instances need to inherit the context of their "parent" AImple instance, i.e. the one on which `choice()` is called. You can't do that using the `new` operator. You should instead have a method that creates the instances with an inherited `variable`.

```
public A[] createChoices(int count, A optionalDefaultValues...) {
    // return an array of clones of itself (possibly with adjusted defaults)
}
```

Comment: What is `count` ? The size of the desire list ?

Comment: I was thinking it would be the size of the list. But it's up to you if you want to pass it in as an argument. Maybe you would simply pass 'new' A objects as prototypes in a varargs list and create the same number of objects.